# Why are there flying pigs in my Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-direwolf20

I played minecraft when suddenly some flying pigs spawned. They look like small pigs flying on a chicken (they are relatively small so it's hard to see):
[image: flying pigs]

They fly down in a straight line and then disappear with an "explosion" effect, but no actual blocks are destroyed. When they fall into water, there is a "bubbles" effect instead. Also, they seem to be immune to attacks. This is one immediately before impact:
[image: pig detail]

I noted that the pigs started to spawn at ~21:00 on 25. December, so maybe it is because of some holiday (presumably christmas)?

Comment: You dare call this Minecraft? :/

Comment: @BlaXpirit It isn't terraria, is it?

Comment: Its a portalgun config called easter egg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flying pigs are a part of the portal mod at Christmas.  If you want to disable just temporarily change your system day to the 26th.

Answer (score 1):

It is an easter egg that is part of the PotalGun mod. They appear on Christmas day (25 December).

To disable them, edit your minecraft/config/PortalGun.cfg file, find the following section, and change easterEgg to 0 (it is set to 1 by default)

```
others {
    # Oh wouldn't you like to know?
    I:easterEgg=0
}
```

The effect is client side only, so you only need to edit this on your game client. Then restart your game.